# Centralized identity management with different providers

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, microservices, openid-connect

I am going to build a web application that allows users to sign in with their Google or Twitter account. I think OpenID Connect(OAuth2) is the standard today to verify the identity.
I also want to provide several API services that can be only accessed with a valid access token from either Google or Twitter.

[image]

For example, all the four API's above are going to be public and so I have to protect from unauthorized users. For NodeJS based API services I can use http://www.passportjs.org/ to protect all APIs.

Assume, in the future the number of API's will be grow for example up to 20 API's and sign in with Facebook account will be also allowed.
Again, all the API's have to be protected and I have to do it 16 times with http://www.passportjs.org/.
In addition add the new provider Facebook, I have to do the changes on all 20 APIs.

[image]

The question is, is their a way to keep centralized, which means in the future when I will provide more the providers for example GITHUB for sign in I would like to do changes in one place not in 20 places.
Is the tool https://www.ory.sh/hydra what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are perhaps the two primary features of OAuth 2.0 and Open ID Connect:

- Federated sign in to your UIs via multiple identity providers and the ability to easily add new options such as GitHub in a centralised manner
- Full control over claims included in access tokens, so that your APIs can authorize requests however you'd like

**FOREIGN ACCESS TOKENS**

You should aim to avoid ever using these in your apps. Your UIs and APIs should only use tokens issued by your own Authorization Server (Ory Hydra), which manages the connection to the Identity Provider. Adding a new sign in method will then just involve centralised configuration changes, with zero code changes in either UIs or APIs.

**IF YOU DON'T HAVE AN AUTHORIZATION SERVER YET**

Maybe have a look at the Curity Identity Server and its [free community edition - use sign in with GitHub](https://curity.io/product/community), which has strong support for both of these areas:

- [Many Authenticators](https://curity.io/product/authentication-service/)
- [Many Options for Issuing Claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scopes-vs-claims/)

**EXTERNAL RESOURCES**

One exception to the above is that your APIs may occasionally need to access a user's Google resources after login, by calling Google APIs. This would require the token issued by Google. It can be managed via an [embedded token approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#embedding-a-token) - though it doesn't sounds like you need that right now.

Comment: Can https://www.ory.sh/hydra be used as AUTHORIZATION SERVER?

Comment: Yep - that's it's role as in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ory/hydra) - unfortunately different people use different names for the role of the central security component that receives OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect messages and issues tokens. I've not used it though it should meet the two main goals I mention above.

Comment: So I can use ory.sh/hydra for what I have described above, right?

Comment: Yes - except that API services should use ory/hydra issued tokens and not google or twitter tokens. I'm fairly sure hydra supports login integration with both providers - and quite a few others also - but check their docs to be sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.